# Texture upside down

Tags: unity, textures, blender

I'm making a top down 3d game. I made a model in blender, uv unwrapped it, and made a texture for it.

Texture in blender from the top:
[image: Texture in blender from the top.]

I saved the model as a .blend file and the texture as a png.

I imported them in to unity, made a material and added the texture.
But, when I add the material to the model the texture is upside down.

Texture in unity from the top:

[image: texture in unity from the top.]

I can't fix it myself and google was not helpful this time. Thank you.

I messed a round with tiling like Fabio S. said:

[image]

With these settings, I got:

[image]

Here is the uv map of the model:

[image]

Comment: Try showing us the UV map of the object, and the source texture. That will help us interpret what we're seeing and figure out where the mapping is going wrong.

Comment: @DMGregory i have updated my post to show the uv map.

Comment: Looks like your flip is on the x-axis.

Comment: @DMGregory could it be something i'm doing wrong in blender?

Comment: I'm not an expert on Blender save & export settings. It's not unusual for 3D software to offer a "flip UV y channel" checkbox to solve common mismatches in coordinate systems, so you can look for a setting like that. An x flip is unusual though...

Comment: In blender does the model have all scale values set to 1.0? A negative scale in the model could cause the flipped material. Ctrl-A-> Scale will apply the scale so they get set to 1.0.

Comment: Also, I don't know if this could cause it, but does the model have any negative scale values in Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for sure why you are having this issue, but I think you should probably try to change the values in your Tiling to -1 to see if that fixes the problem.

[image]

Comment: You might want `Tiling (1, -1)` and `Offset (0, 1)` if it's just the y channel that's flipped. That way we map 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 on that axis while leaving x unchanged.

Comment: @DMgregory i updated my post with the result of your suggesiton.

Comment: @ThePumkinMelon, did you try just playing around with the settings? Tinkering to see if you can get better results?

Comment: @ThePumkinMelon you missed a -1  scale on the Y

Comment: I did mess a round with values. @DMGregory -1 on the Y makes it worse.

Comment: Do you feel like packaging your model and texture into a unitypackage and let us download it? If so, post it on Dropbox or Google Drive, or your favorite cloud storage and post the link.